# How to get two integers separated by space in a char[]?

Tags: c++, istringstream

I will be getting a string of numbers that looks like this.

```
12 45
```

Two integers separated with space.

The output will be 57.

I have tried using,

```
string numbersstream;
cin >> numbersstream;
istringstram twonumbers (numbersstream);
twonumbers >> a >> b;
```

But each time I run it, only a is correct, b isn't.

What other functions is there to help me? Or is this just a coding problem I have?

I got two kinds of suggestions already in the answers.

```
getline(cin,numbersstream);
```

And

```
cin << a << b;
```

Thank you all for your time. Additional methods will be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `numbersstream`

Comment: @Tux-D I've answered your reply with addition codes stating that numbersstream is a string, and I get the stream from a cin function. Thanks for the care, both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your input from cin.  Using `operator>>` is whitespace delimited.  So if the user types "12 45", only the 12 will be extracted.  You could use getline instead:

```
getline(cin,numbersstream);
```

Comment: I've been suspecting that for a while. I used to use a for loop looking for the space. And each time, it fails. I can't find any reference in my book that says cin will ignore a whitespace. But now I know. Thank you very much. It will fix a lot of my problems.

Comment: @Shane: To clarify, it's not just cin, it's *all* istreams.  And it's not always, it's only when using `operator>>`.  Istreams have other input functions which don't do that.  `getline` like I showed you, but also `read`, `get` and some others.

Comment: `istream`s can also be instructed to *preserve* whitespace with the `noskipws` manipulator, and whitespace can then be explicitly captured and ignored with the `ws` manipulator.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. greyfade and Benjamin Lindley.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;

    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a+b << "\n";
}
```

The problem is that in your code:

```
cin >> numbersstream;
```

Only reads one space separated word (ie 12) into the string `numbersstream`. Thus when you build `twonumbers` it actually only has one number in it. Hence it only sets 'a' and 'b' is left undefined.

You could do it your way but what you really need here is to read the whole line into the string:

```
std::getline(std::cin, numbersstream);
istringstram twonumbers (numbersstream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading until the first whitespace character with

```
cin >> numberstream;
```

The following will read everything into the string until a delimiter character is read ('\n') or end-of-file. The delimiter is discarded.

```
getline(cin,numbersstream);
```

Comment: Understood. Someone else has answered for me with the same code. But thank you for your time as well.